# Get Value from Contourplot - Python Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

i have a problem with my contourplot. I have messured data from experimental work, then i interpolated and plot it with matplotlib contourplot. Now i want to validate my interpolation.

For this validation i need to know the plottet value from a specific (x,y) point out of my contourplot. Due to i want to check how close my interpolation at (x,y) to my messured data at (x,y) is.

At the end i want to plot the difference over x.

i hope you understand my problem and can help me!

thanks a lot!

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import griddata
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot

df = pd.read_excel("my_work.xlsx")

x = df.loc["x_messured" ]
y = df.loc["y_messured" ]
z = df.loc["z_messured" ]

x_interp = np.linspace(0, max(x), 200)
y_interp = np.linspace(0, max(y), 200)

z2d = griddata((x, y), z, (x_interp[None,:], y_interp[:,None]))

matplotlib.pyplot.figure()

cs = plt.contour(x_interp, y_interp, z2d)
csf = plt.contourf(x_interp, y_interp, z2d, cmap="viridis")

diff = []
for q in range(len(x)):
    diff.append( abs( z[q] - get_from_z2d(x[q], y[q]) ) )

plot(x, diff)
```

I need the function get_from_z2d()...

Comment: Can you show us with some simple example data so we can more easily understand your problem?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)